# Co-kernel of a vector bundle trivial outside a subset of co-dimension 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety and $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $n$ on $X$. Let $D \subset X$ be a closed subset of co-dimension $2$. Assume the restriction of $E$ on $U:= X \setminus D$ is trivial. Then by Hartog's theorem these $n$ linearly independent sections of $E\vert_U$ can be extended to sections of $E$ on $X$. These sections will define an injection $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n} \to E$.

Question: What will be its co-kernel ?

Comment: If your $X$ is normal, the cokernel is trivial, since $i_*\mathscr{O}_U=\mathscr{O}_X$, where $i$ is the injection of $U$ in $X$.

Comment: That means $E$ is trivial on $X ?

Comment: Yes — again, if $X$ is normal.